# How to access a double pointer structure in another structure

Tags: c, struct

I'm having trouble accessing my double pointer struct within my structure.

```
typedef struct monster
{
    char *name;
    char *element;
    int population;
} monster;

typedef struct region
{
    char *name;
    int nmonsters;
    int total_population;
    monster **monsters;
} region;


region **
readRegion (FILE * infile, int *regionCount)
{
    
    region **temp;
    char garbage[50];
    char garbage2[50];
    
    char rName[50];
    int monsterNum;
    
    fscanf (infile, "%d %s", regionCount, garbage);
    temp = malloc (*regionCount * sizeof (region *));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < *regionCount; i++)
    {
        fscanf (infile, "%s%d%s", rName, &monsterNum, garbage2);
        temp[i] = createRegion (inFile, rName, monsterNum);
    }
    return temp;
}

region *
createRegion (FILE * inFile, char *rName, int nMonsters)
{
    region *r = malloc (sizeof (region));
    char rMonster[50];
    int rLength;
    r->name = malloc ((strlen (rName) + 1) * sizeof (char));
    strcpy (r->name, rName);
    r->nmonsters = nMonsters;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nMonsters; i++)
    {
        r->monsters.name = (nMonsters * sizeof (r->monsters.name));
        fscanf (in, "%s", rMonster);
        
        r->monsters.name = malloc ((strlen (rMonster) + 1) * sizeof (char));
        strcpy (r->monsters.name, rMonster);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Hopefully my code is readable where you can get the jist of what im trying to do with the monster** monsters pointer in my region struct. Any explnation on how to access and use a double struct pointer within a structure would help.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: This code raises a lot of questions, but first: Why `monster **monsters`? Do you need a 2D array? Why `region** temp`? The way you're using double pointers here doesn't make any sense to me. In fact there's far too many pointers here. Why is `int *regionCount` a pointer? My advice: *Stop using so many pointless pointers*.

Comment: The structures were assigned to us to use so you can't edit them in any way shape or form.We need to read in monster names specified to  a certain region and save them to that region name.

Comment: I think a lot of this code is super confused because you prefer to return *arrays of pointers* rather than the more traditional *pointer to array*. As in once you know how many of X you need to load, allocate them all in a contiguous array of memory, then return a pointer to that.

Comment: Oh, if this is academic code taught by a teacher who has their own wonky interpretation of what C is all about that explains a lot. Those structures aren't how C is normally done, nor arguably how it *should * be done. Hope you survive this course without too much damage.

Comment: Yeah signed up late and got a rating 5 professor. Wish me luck

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all background information from your comments there. Please ask a specific question instead of "Any explnation on how to access and use a double struct pointer within a structure would help." Use an example what data you want to access in what function. Is there a problem in the functions shown or do you need help adding other functions?

Comment: I suggest using the term "pointer to pointer" rather than "double pointer", which would refer to a pointer of type `double*`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to clean up and re-interpret your `createRegion` to read a lot more like traditional C:

```
region* createRegion(FILE * inFile, char *rName, int nMonsters) {
  region *r = malloc(sizeof(region));
  char buffer[1024];

  r->name = strdup(rName);

  r->nmonsters = nMonsters;

  r->monsters = calloc(nMonsters, sizeof(monster*));

  for (int i=0; i < nMonsters; i++) {
    // Allocate a monster
    monster *m = malloc(sizeof(monster));

    fscanf(in,"%s", buffer);

    m->name = strdup(buffer);
    m->element = NULL; // TBD?
    m->population = 1; // TBD?

    // Put this monster in the monsters pointer array
    r->monsters[i] = m;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Where the key here is you *must* allocate the monsters. Here it's done individually, but you could also allocate as a slab:

```
region* createRegion(FILE * inFile, char *rName, int nMonsters) {
  region *r = malloc(sizeof(region));
  char buffer[1024];

  r->name = strdup(rName);

  r->nmonsters = nMonsters;

  // Make a single allocation, which is usually what's returned from
  // C functions that allocate N of something
  monsters* m = calloc(nMonsters, sizeof(monster));

  // Normally you'd see a definition like m in the region struct, but
  // that's not the case here because reasons.

  r->monsters = calloc(nMonsters, sizeof(monster*));

  for (int i=0; i < nMonsters; i++) {
    fscanf(in,"%s", buffer);

    m[i].name = strdup(buffer);
    m[i].element = NULL; // TBD?
    m[i].population = 1; // TBD?

    // Put this monster in the monsters pointer array
    r->monsters[i] = &m[i];
  }

  return r;
}
```

Note I've switched out the highly quirky `strlen`-based code with a simple `strdup` call. It's also very odd to see `sizeof(char)` used since on any computer you're likely to interface with, be it an embedded microcontroller or a fancy mainframe, that *will* be 1.

Comment: I think in the 2nd version it should be `r->monsters[i] = &m[i];`.

Comment: @Bodo Good catch, thanks. Didn't go so far as to compile this.

Answer (score 0):

Inasmuch as you are asking about accessing a double pointer inside a structure, I think your issue is mostly about this function:

> ```
> region *
> createRegion (FILE * inFile, char *rName, int nMonsters)
> {
>     region *r = malloc (sizeof (region));
>     char rMonster[50];
>     int rLength;
>     r->name = malloc ((strlen (rName) + 1) * sizeof (char));
>     strcpy (r->name, rName);
>     r->nmonsters = nMonsters;
> ```

**[Point A]**

So far, so good, but here you start to run off the rails.

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < nMonsters; i++)
>     {
>         r->monsters.name = (nMonsters * sizeof (r->monsters.name));
> ```

Hold on.  `r->monsters` has type `monster **`, but you are trying to access it as if it were a `monster`.  Moreover, `r->monsters` has never had a value assigned to it, so there's very little indeed that you can safely do with it.

I think the idea must be that `r->monsters` is to be made to point to a dynamically-allocated array of `monster *`, and that the loop allocates and initializes the monsters, and writes pointers to them into the array.

You need to allocate space for the array, then, but you only need or want to allocate the array once. Do that before the loop, at Point A, above, something like this:

```
      r->monsters = malloc(nMonsters * sizeof(*r->monsters));  // a monster **
```

Then, inside the loop, you need to allocate space for one monster, and assign a pointer to that to your array:<sup>*</sup>

```
    r->monsters[i] = malloc(sizeof(*r->monsters[i]));  // a monster *
```

Then, to access the actual `monster` objects, you need to either dererference and use the direct member selection operator (`.`) ...

```
    (*r->monsters[i]).name = /* ... */;
```

... or use the indirect member selection operator (`->`) ...

```
    r->monsters[i]->name = /* ... */;
```

.  The two are equivalent, but most C programmers seem to prefer the latter style.

At this point, however, I note that in the body of the loop, you seem to be trying to make two separate assignments to the monster's `name` member.  That doesn't make sense, and the first attempt *definitely* doesn't make sense, because you seem to be trying to assign a number to a pointer.

> ```
>         fscanf (in, "%s", rMonster);
>         
>         r->monsters.name = malloc ((strlen (rMonster) + 1) * sizeof (char));
>         strcpy (r->monsters.name, rMonster);
> ```

Using the above, then, and taking advantage of the fact that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, it appears that what you want is

```
        // ...

        r->monsters[i]->name = malloc(strlen(rMonster) + 1);
        strcpy (r->monsters[i]->name, rMonster);
```

And finally,

> ```
>     }
>     return r;
> }
> ```

Note well that corresponding to the two levels of indirection in type `monster **`, each access to an individual monster property via `r->members` requires two levels of derferencing.  In the expressions above, one is provided by the indexing operator, `[]`, and the other is provided by the indirect member access operator, `->`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Or you could allocate space for all of the monsters in one go, before the loop, and inside the loop just initialize them and the array of pointers to them.  The use of a `monster **` suggests the individual allocation approach, but which to choose depends somewhat on how these will be used.  The two options are substantially interchangeable, but not wholly equivalent.